# Dyntopo workflow + Dyntopo vs. Multires?

Tags: sculpting, normal-map, multiresolution

I've checked the Dyntopo option on sculpt mode and now my mesh is with triangles. Is there any way to revert a mesh to the way it was before clicking on Dyntopo?

Is it better to sculpt with Dyntopo or with Multires? Which of the two gives better higher quality results?

There's a great tutorial on youtube where the person first demonstrates the dyntopo sculpting, then does the retopology, and then adds an multi-resolution modifier on the retopology in order to give it a more detailed sculpt. Now is it necessary to have this workflow? Or is it more convenient to first have your high detailed sculpt, then retopology and after that, bake normals from high to low poly?

Link to the video
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k9NAv_q_wfU

Comment: Related: https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98565/sculpting-a-photorealistic-human-face-for-animation-use-the-multiresolution-mod/98566#98566

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Something to be aware of with workflows is there isn't necessarily an objectively 'better' or 'worse' workflow. There are a number of ways to get to the same (or at least very similar) end result, so the workflow you use should be the one that fits you best, and lets you work in a way you like while giving you the best results in the least amount of time.

Now to answer your questions, there is no way to revert back to your mesh once you have started to sculpt with Dyntopo. That's known as a destructive process, as it permanently changes the structure of your mesh. However, if you have just clicked the button and haven't actually started sculpting, you may be able to use the *tris to quads* tool in edit mode. Select all of your faces, then press <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>J</kbd> and it will try and join the triangles into quads. Depending on your mesh this may have varying levels of success.

Dyntopo vs. Multiresolution is a subjective question. There are uses for each tool, and situations where one is better than the other. I discussed this in another question [here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/questions/98565/sculpting-a-photorealistic-human-face-for-animation-use-the-multiresolution-mod/98566#98566).

To answer your final question (and just for future reference you should try to limit your questions per post to just one), the workflow used on the video isn't 'necessary' but may be the best way to achieve the best results. As for convenience, if it works better for you, then do it that way. Part of creating digital art is having fun and being able to express yourself, so you don't want to have a workflow where you're constantly fighting with your tools. Find what works best and stick with it.

Comment: Brenticus, I highly appreciate your response. Thanks for letting me know and answering my questions.